# Display a simple message box

Tags: odoo

How to display a simple message box inside method of a button at the user click.

When the user click on the button he see a message box.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to show a message box before executing the button function then you need to add an attribute conform in your button xml tag. For example

```
<button  name="button_process" string="Proceed" confirm="Do you want to proceed?" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

When user click on this button Proceed a dialog box will be showed with message "Do you want to proceed?", when you click ok on that dialog box, then only the button_process will be executed.

Answer (score 3):

I have Just Add small method in .py file and generate the message box on button click

**XML File**

```
<record id="view_hr_payroll_payslip_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.payroll.payslip.wizards</field>
    <field name="model">hr.payroll.payslip.wizard</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="moves" version="7.0">

        <footer>
            <button  name="generate_msg" string="Click To Me" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>or

        </footer>
    </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

**same name of method are define in my button name attribute in my .py file**

```
from openerp.tools.translate import _

def generate_msg(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    raise osv.except_osv(_("Warning!"), _(" Hello Mehdi Mokni !!."))
```

python Library can be added for covert your message in your Language

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)

Comment: thank you for the answer i show the message but osv.except_osv generates an error in log file of the server :

**2015-05-11 10:54:15,575 4252 ERROR odoo_db openerp.http: Exception during JSON
...                                                                                   
except_orm: (u'Warning!', u' Hello Mehdi Mokni !!.')**

Comment: can u tell me which openerp version u r using ??